# How to find XPath of a class element that has more than one occurrences on the page?

Tags: selenium, xpath, browser

I am trying to make Selenium click upvote buttons on a reddit-like website. The site has entries from different users and each entry has a upvote and downvote button below it. What i want to do is to make Selenium click on the first upvote button ( which belongs to the entry at the top ) on the page. 
I tried to use "Copy XPath" function in Chrome, but all of the upvote buttons on the page return the same XPath:

```
//*[@id="eksico-chevron-up-thick"]/path
```

And this is how the website looks like if needed :

[image]

So, is there any way for finding the XPath of the first upvote button? I was thinking of something like:

```
//*[@id="eksico-chevron-up-thick"]/[1]
```

etc. Thanks in advance.

Edit: The HTML Code of one of the upvote elements:

[image]

Comment: Please add the html of the element you are trying to click

Comment: @SameerArora added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The element that you are trying to click is under `shadow dom` as mentioned in the html structure and currently selenium does not support operation on the elements under the shadow dom.
Reference: https://medium.com/rate-engineering/a-guide-to-working-with-shadow-dom-using-selenium-b124992559f

So, if you want to click on the element, you can use `JavaScriptExecutor` like:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("eksico-chevron-up-thick"));
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

By default, it will click on the first element itself and if you want to click on a specific nth element then you can take the elements in a list and then send the index of that element inside the method to get that element clicked.

Comment: I've never heard of JavaScriptExecutor before, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to click on the first one you could use
`Driver.find_elements_by_xpath(//*[@id="eksico-chevron-up-thick"]/path)[1].click()`